# Firefox Python selenium not going headless

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, geckodriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am trying to make firefox headless and doing exactly as shown in the documentation.

This shouldn't be doing what it is supposed to
the firefox window is appearing even when I am adding the headless argument

```
cap = DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
cap["marionette"] = False

options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument('-headless')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options, capabilities=cap)
```

this should not open the firefox window but it opening the window
[image]
I have never had this kind of problem with chrome and chromedriver

I have downloaded the 64-bit geckodriver binary and it is in PATH
what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Try following code block:

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.headless = True
```

Comment: This looks like it should work... I always use: `add_argument('--headless')` not `options.headless = True` but good answer! +1

Comment: Thanks @MosheSlavin I will keep in mind above suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Options()` not `webdriver.FirefoxOptions()`:

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: still the same , maybe this is a bug isn geckodriver or Firefox

Comment: still same issue